# Change name with formData.set

Tags: javascript, form-data

I have in formData:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="property-photos"; filename="Screen Shot 2017-12-22 at 10.31.21 AM.png"
Content-Type: image/png.
```

This is being sent by a multiple file file input.

I have three photos labeled `property-photos` and would like to use a for loop to change them to `PropertyPhoto1`, `PropertyPhoto2` and `PropertyPhoto3`

How do I use formData.set to change this?

I would have thought it was something similar to:

```
formData.set('PropertyPhoto'+(i+1), fileName, fileType).
```

Comment: `.set()` can only be used to replace an existing key, you can't add a new element with it.

Comment: @Barmar, that's precisely what I wanted to do. I made the below answer work for me by deleting the original. I wanted to replace property-photo with PropertyPhoto1 and since there were possibly three the others would be replaced in sequential order.

Comment: "replace" means to keep the name the same, just change the value.

Comment: You can't use `.set()` to replace `property-photo` with `PropertyPhoto1` because how does it know which one you're trying to remove if the name is different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the name when appending the `File` object. See [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```
let fd = new FormData();
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fd.append("PropertyPhoto" + (i + 1), files[i], "PropertyPhoto" + (i + 1))
}
```